# how to title() dataframe without capitalizing the ( 's)

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to capitalize first letter in dataframe like.

associate's degree
if this code:
df['education']=df['education'].str.title() as result in

Associate'S Degree.

How do I have good code without capitalizing 's

Associate's Degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative could be to use [string.capwords](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.capwords):

```
import string
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=["associate's degree"], columns=['education'])
print(df['education'].apply(string.capwords))
```

**Output**

```
0    Associate's Degree
Name: education, dtype: object
```